# JPGs become zero-byte images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg

I had a few files in my computer that became zero bytes files automatically. When I try to open the files, it says invalid pics. How can I retrieve these images?

Comment: You'll probably need a data recovery tool at this point, like GetDataBack http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-products.htm

Comment: A zero byte file means there is nothing there but a filename entry.  There is nothing to open.  If it was properly deleted, the filename should have been deleted, too, so normal undeletion probably won't work.  If the file contents are still on the drive and uncorrupted, recovery would require a data recovery program, possibly doing a low-level scan.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- Where did the images come from? Can
  you download or copy them again?
- Try a different image viewer. Maybe
  Irfanview or Paint.net
- Use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to search your
  drive for any other instances of the
  file.
- Use a recovery application  like
  [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to try and retrieve it if
  it was deleted.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have a large number of image files which have become zero bytes. I have tried recuva but that sees them as valid files not deleted files and therefore does nothing with them.

I tried http://www.pcinspector.de/Sites/smart%5Frecovery/info.htm?language=1 and have quickly and successfully recovered one of the images. It produces two files; one of zero bytes and another of 2.6 Mbytes which produces a normal image. I imagine I shall be able to recover all the files in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If there are zero bytes in the file, then you cannot retrieve the image from the file.  You may be able to retrieve the image from somewhere else, though.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me once. On chrome, when I saved the image to the disk, the download was successful but the result was a **zero sized image**.

I think the only solution is to **re-download the images** if you got them from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If the images were on your hard drive and readable previously the smart recovery software from http://www.pcinspector.de/Sites/smart_recovery/info.htm?language=1 might recover them.